# Make page refresh if successful login with ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ajax code

```
$("#login_btn").click(function() {
    var url = "core/login.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#sr").serialize(), 
        success: function(data) {
            var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $('.oops').html('<div class="error">'+responseData.oops+'</div>');
            alert(responseData.good);
            if(responseData.good === 1) {
                alert(good) 
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Php code if everything passes

```
 else {
            $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
            $good = 1;
            exit();
        }
```

How come it's not freshing the page with location.reload? Should I be using .done .try?

Comment: You aren't actually sending any output in that PHP snippet.

Comment: no json being sent. Why would you need to reload page? Seems to defeta purpose of using AJAX in the first place

Comment: Are you sure `responseData.good` is a `1` rather than a `'1'`? Try changing `===` to `==`.

Comment: Because if there's an error it would display the error without refrseh if there isn't it would just refresh

Answer (score -1):

Dont refresh, the whole idea of using ajax is that you dont need to. 
You can set your sessions in the ajax php script and pull new content based on the change in session.

That being said, you are missing a ';' at

```
alert(good);
```

Comment: when downvoting please comment, a downvote by it self is pointless.

Comment: in javascript a ';' is not always required!

Comment: no but its a good practice in any language that has certain cases where a semi-colon is required. Any comment on the rest?